# store authorization object to session?

Tags: php, security, authorization

I've built a class that provides some basic "can I do this?" authorization functions for my site, stuff like "can this user view this resource?" or "can this user add an image?"

So the class object is instantiated in quite a few pages (potentially, every page that has a user interaction) using `$authorize = new myAuthorizationClass();`

The `myAuthorizationClass` class then looks up the user's ID and check their access level.

I can then say something like

```
if ($authorize->canAddImage()){
    // do image add stuff
}
```

Is it possible, secure and "best practice" to store this `$authorize` object into the session? Is there another way to avoid the overhead of building this auth object on every page, and doing the DB interactions etc?

I don't think it can be as simple as just saying "set the user's auth level to A, B, or C, and set that in their session!" since their access to a particular resource depends on who owns the resource, what role the user has in the site, etc. and we have to check a few different things depending on what type of resource is being accessed.

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, it is considered bad practice to store authorization information in a session, especially in cookie-based sessions, as a cookie can be very easily stolen over an unsecured wifi and such.

Comment: @truth-- thanks, I think you're right on that, but this would be storing an object that then performs the auth actions as functions. Not sure if this is even possible! However, wanted to weigh in with the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Storing user data within a session (not cookie) is acceptable, as this data is stored on the server side and randomly generated for every user, and as long as your session handling storage is protected, will not be accessible to other users.

If you want to reduce database load by not having to look up the users role/access for every page request, you may want to consider pulling the information upon successful login then storing the (in serialized format) into a session variable. Then, for protected resources, you can unserialize the data stored within the variable, do your check, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Moreover you can store some session object. Use `__sleep()` and `__wake()` methods properly and don't forget to include class definition before `session_start()` (not needed with aoutoload).

Comment: That's not true. How does the server identify you as the owner of that session? It sends you a session ID, usually in the form of a cookie, and that cookie is used to authenticate against the server to present you with your data. However what if that cookie is stolen? The server will mistake the attacker for you, and all of your authorization data will be in his hands.

Comment: @Truth: You are correct, according to PHP: "This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL." But I said "user data", which is fine to store within a session.

Comment: Well, the OP did say he want to save an authorization class, which holds permissions in the site, and not user data.

Comment: To be clear, it is ok to store user and authorization data within a session, it is not ok to store this data via a cookie. Keep the user data / authorization data server side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is considered **bad** practice to store *authorization* data within sessions.

The reason is quite simple, while the data itself is stored on the server side, where it's safe, the weaker link is actually still (like always) on the client.
The server must identify the client who owns the data somehow, that is usually done in a form of a **session_id cookie** sent to the user. That cookie will be sent to the server in each request, and the server will be able to figure out who you are by the (very random) ID.

However, over an unsecured WiFi (or a computer), that cookie can be rather easily stolen by an attacker, which will cause the server to identify him as you.

---

There is no simple way around this, other then SSL and user education. If your site requires very high security (such as money transactions or critical database operations), inform the users about it and advise them to confirm their local security measures.

Also, if your site deals with critical database operations, don't allow anything critical (deletion, table drops etc) done from the web application. Only via the root user.